# Cleaning up 'smart' characters from Word in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ms-word, special-characters, smart-quotes

I need to clean up various Word 'smart' characters in user input, including but not limited to the following:

```
&#8211; EN DASH
&#8216; LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
&#8217; RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
```

Are there any Ruby functions or libraries for mapping these into their ASCII (near-) equivalents, or do I really need to just do a bunch of manual gsubs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTMLEntities](http://rubydoc.info/gems/htmlentities/4.2.4/frames) gem will decode the entities to UTF-8.

You could use [iconv](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/iconv/1.9.2/frames) to transliterate to the closest ASCII equivalents or simple `gsub` or `tr` calls. James Grey has some [blogs](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings) about converting between various character sets showing how to do the transliterations.

```
require 'htmlentities'

chars = [
  '&#8211;', # EN DASH
  '&#8216;', # LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
  '&#8217;'  # RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
]

decoder = HTMLEntities.new('expanded')
chars.each do |c|
  puts "#{ c } => #{ decoder.decode(c) } => #{ decoder.decode(c).tr('–‘’', "-'")} => #{ decoder.decode(c).encoding }"
end

# >> &#8211; => – => - => UTF-8
# >> &#8216; => ‘ => ' => UTF-8
# >> &#8217; => ’ => ' => UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Some gsubs sound like the best bet, especially if you're planning to load an entire extra library to do basically the same thing.